# Changing Button ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button

I have a form with a button whose initial value is `'Submit'` and its ID is `'submit1'` which is used by this:

```
$( function(){
$("#submit1").click(function () {
    alert("i got ");
    var dname = $("#dname").attr('value');
    if(jQuery.trim(dname).length == 0){
        $("#dnametd").append("<span id='requiredsp' class='vanadium-advice vanadium-invalid'>Thissss is a required field.</span>");
        $("#dname").keyup(function () {
            $("#requiredsp").remove();
        });
    }
    else{
var dname = $("#dname").attr('value');
var symptons = $("#symptons").attr('value');
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "method=" +"addDisease"+"&dname="+dname+"&symptons="+symptons+"&status="+"y",
                url:  "classes/disease_type.class.php",
                success: function(){
                gettables();
                    }
               }); 
        $("#newformreg").hide( { direction: "left" }, 1500);
        $("#dname").val('');
        $("#symptons").val('');
    }

    });
});
```

Later on I get data from the server and I get those data in the above form with a hidden textbox for id and also I change the buttons value to Update and id to update as below.

```
  function doEdit(id){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "method=" +"getDisease"+"&did="+id,
                url:  "classes/disease_type.class.php",
                success: function(myVar){
                    $("#newformreg").show( { direction: "left" }, 1000);
                    arr3=myVar.split('%');
                    $('<input>').attr({type:'hidden',id:'did'}).appendTo("#insertForm");
                    $("#did").val(arr3[0]);
                    document.getElementById("dname").value=arr3[1];
                    //$("#dname").val(arr3[1]);
                    $("#symptons").val(arr3[2]);
                    $("#submit1").prop({id:'update',value:'Update'});
                    //document.getElementById("submit").value="Update";
                    //document.getElementById("submit").id="update";
                },
                }); 
                            }

            $( function() {
            $("#update").click(function () {
            var upvalue = $("#update").attr('value');
            alert("updateclick");
            alert(upvalue);
            var dnamee = document.getElementById("dname").value;

            if(jQuery.trim(dname).length == 0){
                $("#dnametd").append("<span id='requiredsp' class='vanadium-advice vanadium-invalid'>Thissss is a required field.</span>");
                $("#dname").keyup(function () {
                    $("#requiredsp").remove();
                });
            }
            else{
                alert("proper");
            var did = $("#did").attr('value');      
            var dname = $("#dname").attr('value');
            var symptons = $("#symptons").attr('value');

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "method=" +"updateDisease"+"&dname="+dname+"&symptons="+symptons+"&did="+did+"&doUpdate="+"edit",
                url:  "classes/disease_type.class.php",
                success: function(){
                    $("#msgdiv").addClass("msg success").add('<span>Record Updated Successfuly</span>');
                    }
               }); 
            }
        }); 
    alert("out");
           });
```

But even after doing this, whenever I click on update it executes the above submit button's function and doesn't update.
Also when my page opens it gives me above `alert("out");`. I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$("#update").click()` to bind a click event, but the "update" id does not exist when the page loads for the first time.

In order to bind events dynamically you need to use the `.on()` method. look [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for further details.

**EDIT**:

Your code is not writtent very well, I'd suggest you give the button one ID (#submitBtn) and give it a class of update/save. then you do this:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('save')){
    //do save code
    }
    else{
      //do update code
    }
}
```

Comment: dude when i get data from server and change buttons id=update..its show me new id as update in firebug..so is it really changing to new id?

Comment: It is changing, but its like you removed old element and added a new element with id update. click() just don't catch dynamic elemnts, only elements that are there when the page first loaded

Comment: dude i changed my code editing as this `$("#update").on("click", function(){`..but still on click of update button it exe submit function

Comment: The code binding the update click event, is in the doEdit function, when do you run this function? I'd suggest you take it out of the function.

Comment: there is a edit img..on click on edit image doedit function gets call.

Comment: So you are only binding the update click event if an image is clicked, if no image was clicked that event is not bound.

Comment: yes bro..also i m not able to get y its exe submit function above when i click update button.

Comment: I suggest you read a bit more about jquery binding and play with it a bit to get a good grasp of it: http://blog.tivix.com/2012/06/29/jquery-event-binding-methods/, also see my edited answer

Comment: k..thnx bro...will try it out.

Comment: dude still same problem...it 1st goes to submit function and than compares class with hasclass n exe if()

Comment: Please edit your question and post the new code, and state exactly what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("out");
```

is working fine.As you are using it in code 
 **$( function() {** that means on ready.